# SQL3550W: ... target column has been defined as GENERATED ALWAYS

Tags: db2

I am trying to export + import data from a table in a db2 database to another. 
But while running the export command I am getting the following error.

`SQL3550W  The field value in row "26" and column "17" is not NULL, but the
target column has been defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.`

and

`SQL3185W  The previous error occurred while processing data from row "26" of
the input file.`

Why is this error coming and how can I fix it.

**The Table**

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY_CLIENT (
        CLIENTGUID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
        TYPECODE VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
        COMPANYNAME VARCHAR(150),
        LASTNAME VARCHAR(150),
        FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(150),
        MIDDLEINITIAL VARCHAR(150),
        PREFIX VARCHAR(10),
        SUFFIX VARCHAR(10),
        SEX VARCHAR(10),
        DATEOFBIRTH TIMESTAMP,
        DATEOFDEATH TIMESTAMP,
        TAXID VARCHAR(60),
        EMAIL VARCHAR(300),
        XMLDATA CLOB(1073741824) INLINE LENGTH 276,
        UPDATEDGMT TIMESTAMP,
        LEGALRESIDENCECOUNTRYCODE VARCHAR(3),
        LASTNAME_LOWER VARCHAR(150) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((LOWER(LASTNAME))),
        FIRSTNAME_LOWER VARCHAR(150) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((LOWER(FIRSTNAME))),
        COMPANYNAME_LOWER VARCHAR(150) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((LOWER(COMPANYNAME))),
        TAXID_LOWER VARCHAR(60) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((LOWER(TAXID))),
        ALTERNATENAME1 VARCHAR(150),
        ALTERNATENAME2 VARCHAR(150),
        ALTERNATENAME3 VARCHAR(150),
        ALTERNATENAME4 VARCHAR(150),
        ALTERNATENAME5 VARCHAR(150),
        ADDITIONALPREFIX VARCHAR(10),
        ADDITIONALSUFFIX VARCHAR(10),
        TAXIDTYPE VARCHAR(10),
        TITLE VARCHAR(10),
        MARITALSTATUS VARCHAR(10),
        BIRTHCOUNTRYCODE VARCHAR(3),
        CITIZENSHIPCOUNTRYCODE VARCHAR(3),
        BIRTHREGIONCODE VARCHAR(10),
        PRIMARYPHONE VARCHAR(60),
        TEXTFIELD1 VARCHAR(765),
        TEXTFIELD2 VARCHAR(765),
        CHECKBOX1 VARCHAR(9),
        CHECKBOX2 VARCHAR(9),
        RADIO1 VARCHAR(10),
        RADIO2 VARCHAR(10),
        COMBO1 VARCHAR(10),
        COMBO2 VARCHAR(10),
        DATE1 TIMESTAMP,
        DATE2 TIMESTAMP
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same IXF files created by db2move export, you can manually load the data using db2 import with the MODIFIED BY IDENTITYOVERRIDE parm for those tables that require it.

Answer (score 0):

The columns marked `GENERATED ALWAYS` are derived columns that are automatically generated from other columns.  You cannot manually set a value to a column that is generated automatically.

One solution is to only import the columns that are not `GENERATED ALWAYS`.  There may be another way to load the data without obeying column constraints ([perhaps `LOAD`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html)?), but I am not sure about this (the documentation is not clear), and it likely depends on your version of DB2.